# Most basic controller doesn't work

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I'm breaking my head over a problem that I don't understand. I tried creating an API controller to do some stuff, but nothing worked , so I went back step by step to a point that my controller is the same as in a tutorial I'm following:

```
public class CityController : Controller
{
    public CityController()
    {
    }


    [HttpGet("city")]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new List<object>()
        {
            new { id = 1, Name ="asd"},
            new { id = 2, Name ="dsa"}
        });
    }
```

In my startup:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddMvc();
        ...
   }


   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "City", action = "Index" }
                );
        }
         );
    }
```

It still doesn't return anything to me via Postman ...... I can't understand why?!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I understand you do /City/Get as your path? in your startup you defined action as Index yet Index doesn't exist in your controller? Maybe Get should be Index instead?

Comment: But doesn't the path inside the `HttpGet` override the default path ? @Adriani6 , nevertheless , I'll try it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I never used parameters inside it, if I was you I would remove the parameter from HttpGet too and leave it just blank.

Comment: I tried leaving it blank , and use `http:***/city` and also `/city/get` , both still raising the error in Postman @Adriani6

Comment: You need something like this https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/

Comment: with the code you posted, the request to `yourSiteName/city` will return the json response. Did you try that in a browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that In postman you will need to set the appropriate content type in your headers such as:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

The URL would then be something like:-

```
http://xxx:999/City
```

**UPDATE**
This works for me.

URL

```
http://localhost:57909/api/values
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new List<object>()
        {
            new { id = 1, Name ="asd"},
            new { id = 2, Name ="dsa"}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do that In postman ? (Btw, I used Postman to return json files two weeks ago, everything worked fine)

Comment: Inside your request within postman, select the headers link, on the right of the screen click the Bulk Edit link and paste Content-Type:application/json

Comment: Nope :/ still getting `Could not get any response`

Comment: Even the template of an API application doesn't work for me :S I tried building a new project, and use the default controller they're offering them and the result is the same. I suspect its some settings or preferences or something . Any thoughts?

Comment: okay, for me, creating a new VS 2017 ASP.Net Core 2,0 Web Api project and pressing F5 to run, opens up a browser showing ["value1","value2"] in the browser and a Url of http://localhost:47726/api/values. What do you see?

Comment: If I run it Via VS it works. If I run it via postman it doesn't .

Comment: copy the url from the browser which vs starts up. Paste that in Postman

Comment: If you are using IIS Express, the site has to be running in VS before postman can hit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost] //whichever you prefer, I am fond of HttpPost for a couple of reasons so I'd recommend using that.
    public IHttpActionResult City() //add string city or any input class variable if you're taking any inputs
    {
        return Ok(new List<object>()
        {
            new { id = 1, Name ="asd"},
            new { id = 2, Name ="dsa"}
        }); //This will return a JSON serialized result
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs may look like this:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
         }
     }
```

If you go for `HttpPost` then be sure to configure Postman accordingly.